Keycloak truststore issue authenticating with mTLS
Description
Greetings,
I'm trying to authenticate to a client (myclient_mTLS) with mTLS (x509) authentication and I'm getting 401 unauthorized.
I'm deploying keycloak on AWS on an EC2 instanced served by an application load balancer which has SSL passthrough enabled.
This is my server configuration:
sudo docker run -d \
  --name keycloak-prod \
  -v /certificates:/certificates \
  -v /certificates:/opt/keycloak/conf/truststores \
  --network=host \
  -e KC_PROXY=edge \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=pass \
  -e KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=pass \
  -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true \
  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:25.0.4 \
  start \
  --features=token-exchange \
  --tls-hostname-verifier=ANY \
  --https-client-auth=request \
  --https-certificate-file=/certificates/subdomain_body.pem \
  --https-certificate-key-file=/certificates/key.pem \
  --hostname=<domain> \
  --https-port=8443 \
  --proxy-headers=xforwarded \
  --db=postgres \
  --db-url=jdbc:postgresql://<domain>:5432/postgres \
  --db-username=pass \
  --db-password=pass \
  --cache=ispn \
  --health-enabled=true

In this folder "/opt/keycloak/conf/truststores" I put every certificate that I use, namely root certificate, domain certificate and the certificate that I want to use to authenticate myself.
When I do this command:
curl -X POST "https://internal-keycloak-926077843.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
    --cert /certificates/fredflinstone-crt.pem \
    --key /certificates/fredflinstone-key.pem \
    --cacert /certificates/rootCA-crt.pem \
    -d "client_id=myclient_mTLS" \
    -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
    -v 

I'm getting always 401 unauthorized. The fredflinstone and rootCA certificates are all in the truststores that I mentioned above.
Keycloak error message:
2024-08-28 09:53:52,916 ERROR [org.keycloak.services] (executor-thread-4) KC-SERVICES0017: Unknown result status
2024-08-28 09:53:52,917 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-4) type="CLIENT_LOGIN_ERROR", realmId="f4d40c0e-b423-4307-9f2c-e102285e4f42", realmName="master", clientId="myclient_mTLS", userId="null", ipAddress="10.33.21.157", error="invalid_client_credentials", grant_type="client_credentials"

My client configuration is the following:

Can anyone point me to a solution?
Thank you

I just found out the issue.
The aws load balancer passes the certificate through this header X-Amzn-Mtls-Clientcert which is not recognized by keycloak.
This means that despite the traffic is encrypted and the certificates are all correct, keycloak does not know what cert is encrypting the traffic and is not able to compare with the trust store.
This is an AWS and keycloak limitations as it is not possible to update the headers.
Cheers
